# Can't restart PyCharm under win7 - java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: pycharm

I sent to following to JetBrains, but maybe one of you can help me

Thanks in advance

Oshrat

I can't restart PyCharm and get the following error:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:110)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannel.doBind(OioServerSocketChannel.java:140)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.run(ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.java:67)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried erasing Pycharm's caches and kill java related processes, but only restarting my PC helped fixing the problem.

I should say, that I'm getting 10054 error, while installing/uninstalling sniffing softwares such as wireshark/nmap/npcap.
After the installation at some point, my python server debugged in Pycharm receives 10054 error repeatedly (see below), consumes around 25% cpu and stops running.

10054 error:

```
handle: <Handle BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 130, in 
_read_from_self
    data = self._ssock.recv(4096)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host
```

I'd appreciate if you can shed some light as for what can cause this behavior and what can/should I do in order to avoid restart and allow Pycharm to restart properly after this scenario.